# Is constructor delegation possible with constructor templates?

Tags: c++, c++11, syntax, constructor

Consider the following snippet from an imaginary implementation of a `shared_ptr` class:

```
template <class T>
class shared_ptr
{ 
    template<class U>
    shared_ptr(const shared_ptr<U>& other)
    {
       //do something
    }
    //to suppress the compiler from generating a copy-constructor, as the above template doesn't count
    shared_ptr(const shared_ptr<T>& other) 
    {
       //do the same thing as above
    }
};
```

Would it be possible to delegate the call of non-template `shared_ptr` to the template version with `U=T`? I tried the following syntax but it didn't work

```
shared_ptr(const shared_ptr<T>& other)
     :shared_ptr<T>(other)
{
}
```

Is there a syntax for delegating to a specific instantiation of a template constructor?

Comment: Write a private constructor with a dummy second parameter; delegate both to that.

Comment: Isn't there a `class shared_ptr` missing after `template <class T>`?